# Firebase add/link password to existing federated provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm allowing user to Sign Up with Google, Facebook or Email. Follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) I know how to link multiple auth provider to the same account but  here is my scenario

Let say an user create account with Google or Facebook but later(after his account created) he want to set password so he can login with email and password as well. I know how to link an email/password account with other federated provider(google, facebook) but not the other way. My only though is to create an new account with that new password and email associated with the method they choose in early stage but it will not work due to email already exist. I even enable `allow multiple account with same address` at my console but it return `ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE` so I think it doesn't work with email/password.

So how can I add password to that account after sign up with Facebook or Google? Thank in any advace.

Answer (score -1):

From the [documentation on linking account providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking#link-auth-provider-credentials-to-a-user-account):

> Email-password sign-in

```
AuthCredential credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email, password);
```

And then you link the credential with the existing Google/Facebook accont with:

> Pass the `AuthCredential` object to the signed-in user's `linkWithCredential` method:

```
mAuth.getCurrentUser().linkWithCredential(credential)
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "linkWithCredential:success");
                FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                updateUI(user);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "linkWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(AnonymousAuthActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                updateUI(null);
            }
            // ...
        }
    });
```

**Update**

use `signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` instead of `linkWithCredential`, because `linkWithCredential` is deprecated.